# how to solve version error createStackNavigator?

Tags: npm, version

```
E:\react_test\first\Test>npm install @react-navigation/stack                   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: Test@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@5.9.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^5.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@6.0.0-next.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/stack@"^6.0.0-next.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\BISHAWJIT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BISHAWJIT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-17T05_20_15_312Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove old package try this package
yarn add @react-navigation/stack
```

Comment: I create a new project. But same issue

Comment: @iitpinfotech can you put here your version with attach screenshot

Comment: @iitpinfotech add with package : yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view ( its is compulsary)

Comment: "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-native": "0.64.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
        "react-native-navigation": "^7.11.3",
        "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"